# How to use reflect.NewAt on interface{}?

Tags: go, reflection, unsafe

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

type Stu struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func MakeStu() interface{} {
    return Stu{
        Name: "Test",
    }
}

func main() {
    jsonData := []byte(`{"name":"New"}`)
    t1 := MakeStu()
    t2 := MakeStu()
    t3 := MakeStu()

    json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &t1)
    fmt.Println(t1) //Type of t1 becomes map[string]interface{} instead of struct Stu

    newPointer := reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(t2).Type()).Interface()
    json.Unmarshal(jsonData, newPointer)
    fmt.Println(newPointer) //It works,but it need allocate memory to hold temp new variable

    brokenPointer := reflect.NewAt(reflect.ValueOf(t3).Type(), unsafe.Pointer(&t3)).Interface()
    json.Unmarshal(jsonData, brokenPointer)
    fmt.Println(brokenPointer) // I want to get the pointer of original type based on the existed variable t3,but it crashes.
}
```

If I don't know the concrete type of the interface{} when coding,I can't use interface.(Type) to cast.
so how to use reflect.NewAt on interface{}?

If there is an interface that contains a method who returns interface{} whose concrete type is struct, but I can't determine the type of struct when coding. I need use json.Unmarshal to decode data that encoded by json. I don't want to get map[string]interface{} , so I need make the receiver's type that is the pointer of concrete type of the interface{} . Using reflect.New is easy but costing extra memory, so I am curious about how to use reflect.NewAt with existing interface{}.

Comment: Your code makes no sense (to me). Could you clarify what exactly you are trying to do? This looks like a XY problem.

Comment: If there is an interface that contains a method who returns interface{} whose concrete type is struct, but I can't determine the type of struct when coding. I need use json.Unmarshal to decode data that encoded by json.  I don't want to get map[string]interface{} , so I need make the receiver's type that is the pointer of concrete type of the interface{} . Using reflect.New is easy but costing extra memory, so I am curious about how to use reflect.NewAt with existing interface{}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to spend a few sentences explaining what the problem is.

The function `MakeStu()`, which we have no control over, returns the empty interface - not a concrete type. This will make the concrete type "invisible" to `json.Unmarshal()`, and `json.Unmarshal()` treats it as the empty interface, not as the concrete type `Stu`. Somehow we must convey the concrete type to the unmarshaller.

I would solve this problem with a type switch:

```golang
func main() {
    jsonData := []byte(`{"name":"New"}`)
    t1 := MakeStu()

    switch c := t1.(type) {
    default:
        _ = json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &c)
        t1 = c
    }

    fmt.Println(t1)
}
```

The type switch turns the empty interface into a concrete type, and `json.Unmarshal()` will treat it as such. You will probably still have the extra allocation, but the code is more readable, and you're not depending on reflection.

If I was feeling really adventurous, I would add a helper function accepting a pointer to an empty interface like this:

```golang
func unmarshal(data []byte, i *interface{}) (err error) {
    switch c := (*i).(type) {
    default:
        err = json.Unmarshal(data, &c)
        *i = c
    }

    return err
}
```

That would enable usage like this:

```golang
    jsonData := []byte(`{"name":"New"}`)
    t1 := MakeStu()
    unmarshal(jsonData, &t1)
```

This looks clean to me and doesn't involve reflection, but it doesn't use `reflect.NewAt()` as you suggested yourself. I hope you find my suggestions useful none the less.

Comment: Very nice ! Why didn't I think of this way? LOL.